# Getting value of msg in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 179
        [user_id] => 191
        [behandeling] => msg
    )
)
```

For some reason i can't get the value of 'behandeling' .. i have tried several ways, like:

console.debug(msg[0].behandeling);

Some more info about building the array:

```
$d[] = array('id' => $row['id'],
        'user_id' => $row['user_id'],
        'behandeling' => $row['behandeling']);
//print_r($d);
//echo json_encode($d);
```

If i use print_r($d), the value of behandeling = CORRECT.
If i use json_encode($d), the value of behandeling will be null..

EDIT:

I think i found the problem.. When submitting the data, the data is being send unescaped in this way:
`var data = 'actie=Wijzig&module=treatment&treatments=' + treatment.val();`

This means if there are certains characters which need to be escaped, & etc.. the data string gets broken... which results in null and/or half msgs...

EDIT2:

The finding described above is very important, but describes a different section of the site. Saving the data is going fine now, but still having difficulties returning the value of the data of SOME messages..

Comment: That's a PHP array. How **exactly** are you sending that to the browser?

Comment: By echo'ing it.. print_r. The reason why i do that is if i use json_encode, the [behandeling] value in the array becomes null, while there is a result...

Comment: I added some information to my question.

Comment: Question: how are you parsing the output from PHP? I understand PHP is outputting a JSON-encoded string, but on the javascript end i assume you're using AJAX? If so, are you using a library such as jQuery?

Comment: Im using AJAX.. Just do an AJAX request, and on success i want to enter the value of behandeling into a textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments that's a PHP array, you could try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myArray = <?=json_encode($array)?>;
  var behandeling = myArray[0].behandleing;
</script>
```

**Update:**

I believe Javascript is interpreting the JSON as a regular string due to your `content-type` header.
You should try adding

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

when outputting your JSON.

Alternatively, if for whatever reason you can't change the headers and you're using jQuery you can try:

```
var parsed = $.parseJSON(ajaxResults);
var behandling = parsed[0].behandling;
```

Without jQuery you can use `eval` however there are security implications involved.

Comment: When i used json_encode in my AJAX, i get the following result: [{"id":"179","user_id":"191","behandeling":null}]